# not suitable method found to override generic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

```
public class SomeRepository<TContext> : IDisposable
            where TContext : DbContext, new()
        {
            protected TContext context;
            protected SomeRepository()
            { }

        public virtual void Create<T>(T item) where T : class, new()
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    internal class SomeCrud : SomeRepository<SomeContext>
    {
        public override void Create(Product item)
        {
            ....
        }     
    }
```

}

I got error on public override void Create(Product item) not suitable method found to override.Please somebody see the mistake?If I'm writing like this:

```
        public override void Create<Product>(Product item)
        {
            ....
        }
```

I can't see a Product type
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this solution:

```
public class SomeRepository<TContext, T> where TContext : DbContext where T : class, new()
{
    public virtual void Create(T item) { }
}

internal class SomeCrud : SomeRepository<SomeContext, Product>
{
    public override void Create(Product item) { }
}
```

You actually should define the constraints of the product in the generic definition.
Note the `T` in `SomeRepository<TContext, T>`

---

You can try

```
    public void Create<T>(T item) where T : Product
    {           
    }
```

but why then use generics?

Comment: Constraints for override and explicit interface implementation methods are inherited from the base method, so they cannot be specified directly
Method in repository is working good, but Create in inherited class should be another from parent

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. You cannot change the signature in the override the way you want.

Comment: Aphelion look:) I have virtual methods for standart cruds oiperation in base class, somtimes in derived class I have to changed some operation.

Comment: @BeginerDummy Well okay. In that case I think you should not be using generics at all.

Comment: Yes but someRepository has a methods that in most cases I don't wanna touch, sometimes I have to add some instruction in derived that's why I signed it virtual.
I'm using cruds from base class for all choices like this: derivedInstance.DoSome<SomeClass>(int id){doing something}
Repository pattern.
I need this 4 methods in baseclass generics.